# What is the method of storing contents of _m128i into an int array?

Tags: x86, sse, simd, intrinsics

We have the intrinsic `_mm_storeu_ps` to store `__m128` into a float array. However, I don't see any equivalent for integers. I was expecting something like `_mm_storeu_epi32`, but that doesn't exist. So, what is the way of storing a `_m128i` into an int array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its name is [`_mm_storeu_si128()`](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#text=_mm_storeu_si128&expand=5203,5203).