# What is the avx2 instruction to store 8 integers?

Tags: c++, c, x86, simd, avx2

I want to store the 8 integers from a `__m256i` variable to an array of 8 x 32 bit `int`s. I thought the instruction for that would be `_mm256_store_epi32`, but I get an error that this instruction doesn't even exist!

Comment: Hint: you might have guessed the answer from [your previous similar question about storing int vectors with SSE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43018299/what-is-the-method-of-storing-contents-of-m128i-into-an-int-array). ;-)

Comment: There is no need for that instruction you mentioned. That is usual for floating-point storage. Integers are fixed-point and all 32-bit, 16-bit, and 8-bit can be stored by the same instruction of `_mm256_store_si256` and `_mm256_storeu_si256`

Comment: @FackedDeveloper Technically, there would be no need for different store functions for `double` and `float` vectors either, since they all just copy the vector bitwise. However, having different intrinsics helps maintaining type-safety (and actually having different hardware instructions may help a CPU with pipelining).

Comment: @chtz, you are right. but, what does happen if somebody stores some `double`s as `float`s (IEEE standard restriction)! But for integer, you can load `short`s and apply some computation then store them as `int`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at the [Intel Intrinsics Guide](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#techs=AVX,AVX2&cats=Store). Depending on whether your destination is aligned, you need [`_mm256_store_si256`](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#text=_mm256_store_si256&expand=5159) or [`_mm256_storeu_si256`](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#text=_mm256_storeu_si256&expand=5159,5205).